# The shortcuts for measurement units: cm and dm

Tags: unit-of-measure

I have to write a math book and I'm using often the following measurement units: **centimeter** (cm), **decimeter** (dm). Can you provide me the shortcut which will output **cm** and **dm**. For **meter**(m) I've found the following shortcut **\meter -> m**.

Comment: Use `siunitx`. If you need to write numerical values, it produces a correct `unbreakable thin space` between number and unit.

Comment: `\meter` is not a standard macro, so you must have included some package that defines it. `siunitx`, as @Bernard mentions is one such package.

Comment: OT, but the unit is called 'metre' (I know it's common in the US to spell it 'meter' but in technical writing the international standard applies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `siunitx` the shortcuts are already there. `\dm` and `\cm` are already provided: see page 36 of `siunitx` manual (version from 2016/03/01). Shorter shortcuts you will not find. (There are two packages `siunits` and `siunitx`, I prefer the latter.)

Comment: By default those will only work inside `\si` or `\SI` of course, though you can make them available outside these as well, with the `free-standing-units` class option. (And by the way, there are other packages for units as well, e.g. `units`.)

Comment: You could with `siunitx` define your own shortcuts: `\newcommand{\DM}[1]{\SI{#1}{\dm}}` and use it as `\DM{2.5}`

Comment: Was that addressed to me? I'm not sure what you were trying to say, the point I  was trying to make is that `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{siunitx}\begin{document}1\,\dm\end{document}` will throw an error.

Comment: to be used like this:`\begin{document}\SI{1}{\dm}\end{document}‌​`. Therefore my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I'm obviously aware of `\SI`, but your answer says nothing about that (or `\si` or the `free-standing-units` option), which I think it should. Looking at the answer alone, a user might think that the code I posted above should work. (Sorry if I'm unclear or nitpicking.)

Comment: The original question was to provide shortcuts for dm and cm. The solution \DM with the defined macro is obviously one of the shortest to think of and which is even better easy to remember. It is also easy to be extended in order to reflect the possibilities of the \SI macros. Therefore I like it and would use it myself.

Comment: But your original answer (which still stands) has *no mention of that whatsoever*.